# How to get first grand child of an array inside of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with 10 elements. Each element is also an array and each of their children are objects.

Lets call it "array".

array[0] gives me the first element. It is filled with 20 objects.

I want to get the first one, and then a value in that object, such as this:

```
var id = array[0].getFirstElement().id;
```

How do I do it?

I tried array[0][0] and other things but didn't work.

Comment: Can you post your code that creates this array?

Comment: arr[0][0].id should work in javascript

Comment: post a data sample

Comment: Sorry, array[0][0].id works, I was careless. Not deleting question, maybe someone will need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this example

```
array = [[{id:2, ...}, ...], ...]
```

You need `array[0][0].id`

Answer (score 0):

See a for in loop: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

for you something like this may work (not tested)

```
for(var prop in array[0]){
  if( array[0].hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
    console.log("array[0]." + prop.id + " = " + array[0][prop].id);
  } 
  //and because you only want the first
  break;
}
```

Comment: `array[0]` is an array itself, so a for-in loop is not ideal there.

Comment: Gave this as an answer because he said it was filled with objects... Seems like I misunderstood a little. Thought he was looking for `array[0].object1.id`, where the name object1 would be unknown... This would work in that case ;)